Apache PDFBox - Checkbox already checked is then set to unchecked
I'm new using pdfbox (v 3.0.3) but i have a strange problem. I load this pdf where the given checkbox is already checked (i see it opening the pdf and in debug mode) but then when i send this pdf via mail the given checkbox is unchecked. Do you have any suggestion?
fun generatePdf(){
val pdf = this::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pdf/role.pdf")
    ?: throw FileNotFoundException("PDF template not found at pdf/role.pdf")
val pdfTemplate = Loader.loadPDF(pdf.readAllBytes())
this.populateTemplateFields(pdfTemplate, "newMail")
}

private fun populateTemplateFields(
    pdfTemplate: PDDocument,
    newMail: String,
)
{
    val acroForm = pdfTemplate.documentCatalog.acroForm

    val checkbox = acroForm.getField("chkbox1") as PDCheckBox
    checkbox.check()
    acroForm.getField("new_mail").setValue(newMail)
   
}

when i retrieve the checkbox, i already see that checkbox.isChecked is true, i tried to "force" it using the check() method, but then the resulting checkbox is unchecked viewing the pdf. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks
Note that the field newUser is correctly set
Link to the given PDF https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wnXrMTfnMaPax4es-CAXa0VD6s7MFzEK/view?usp=sharing

I don't know if it makes a difference but the checkbox is read only, i also tried to make it not read only but it doesen't change anything. Plus, the given checkbox doesen't become read/write :/

@TilmanHausherr i have shared the PDF at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wnXrMTfnMaPax4es-CAXa0VD6s7MFzEK/view?usp=sharing. I don't think i have this filtering problem because i dont receive any exception and the file is correctly loaded but i'll investigate

Yes i just changed the code snippet. The field is "chkPrivacy1".

I'm able to reproduce it. Although it doesn't make sense that you call check() when it is already checked, I can confirm that it the checkmark no longer displays the modified file, and Adobe refuses to open it.

Until this is fixed, use 2.0 or add CompressParameters.NO_COMPRESSION to the save() call. I have created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5927

@TilmanHausherr thanks a lot!!

The cause of this bug is described in PDFBOX-5927 and it will be fixed in 3.0.4, a snapshot build is available here.
Alternatively, save your files with compression disabled by using CompressParameters.NO_COMPRESSION, or use version 2.
